# Printing Data on jTextArea in a table form

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

Actually I'm retrieving data from mysql and wanted to print that data on the `jTextArea` in the table form using swing.

Comment: Thanks alot. I just searched it.

Comment: @Maaz please please if you provide screenshots, use screenshots that are not a pixelated mess of grey and black. The screenshot provided by you is unusable, so I took the liberty to remove it. Aside from that people around here prefer not to have too much talk around a question, so I cleaned that up a little, too...

Comment: JTable is much easier to use, but in case anyone else reads this question, you can display tabular data with a JTextArea by using a mono space font and counting characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JTable instead of JTextArea, an example would be:

```
// load the data from database into a vector
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
    Vector data = new Vector();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Vector row = new Vector();
        row.add(resultSet.getString(1));
        row.add(resultSet.getInt(2));
        data.add(row);
    }

    // initialize the column names
    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    columnNames.add("Name");
    columnNames.add("Num");

    // create the jtable with the data and the column names
    JTable jTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.add(new JScrollPane(jTable));
    jFrame.pack();
```

Details on JTable can be found on Oracle JTable tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html